# Wiremock response template to use json passed in as request query parameter

Tags: json, wiremock

Provided with the following request:

```
http://myserver:8080/api/userinfo?Logins=%5B%22admin%40my.domain%22%5D
```

How would I get the first value in urlencoded-json array of values found in `Logins` query parameter to output in Wiremock response templating?

Following are my attempts:

```json
{
  "response": {
    "jsonBody": {
      "logins": "{{request.query.Logins}}",
      "jsonPathLogins": "{{jsonPath request.query.Logins '$'}}",
      "jsonPathLogins0": "{{jsonPath request.query.Logins '$.[0]'}}",
      "jsonPathQueryLogins": "{{jsonPath request.query '$.Logins'}}",
      "jsonPathQueryLogins0": "{{jsonPath request.query '$.Logins.[0]'}}",
      "loginsCut": "{{cut request.query.Logins.[0] '\"'}}",
      "loginsCutQuot": "{{cut request.query.Logins.[0] '&quot;'}}",
      "loginsReplace": "{{replace request.query.Logins.[0] '\"' '*'}}",
      "loginsReplaceQuot": "{{replace request.query.Logins.[0] '&quot;' '*'}}"
    }
  }
}
```

and my response is always the same:

```json
{
  "logins": "[&quot;admin@my.domain&quot;]",
  "jsonPathLogins": "[&quot;admin@my.domain&quot;]",
  "jsonPathLogins0": "[&quot;admin@my.domain&quot;]",
  "jsonPathQueryLogins": "[&quot;admin@my.domain&quot;]",
  "jsonPathQueryLogins0": "[&quot;admin@my.domain&quot;]",
  "logins": "[&quot;admin@my.domain&quot;]",
  "loginsCut": "[&quot;admin@my.domain&quot;]",
  "loginsCutQuot": "[&quot;admin@my.domain&quot;]",
  "loginsReplace": "[&quot;admin@my.domain&quot;]",
  "loginsReplaceQuot": "[&quot;admin@my.domain&quot;]"
}
```

What am I missing? How do I combine those methods to unwrap my value from that double JSON encoding (or somehow strip wrapping symbols)?

Answer (score 1):

So far what I've come up with is the following wrapper:

```
{
  "response": {
    "jsonBody": {
      "logins": "{{replace(replace (replace (replace (urlEncode request.query.Logins decode=True) '%22' '') '%5B' '') '%5D' '') '%40' '@'}}"
    }
  }
}
```

It looks awful and prone to edge cases, but work for some simple ones. I would gladly accept an answer which does not rely on replacing urlEncoded sequences directly the way I did it.

EDIT:
Here's another regex-based solution which works in my email-like case and looks a bit cleaner, but would fail in any other case:

```json
{
  "response": {
    "jsonBody": {
      "login": "{{regexExtract request.query.Logins '\b(.+?@.+)\b' 'parts'}}{{join parts ' '}}",
    }
  }
}
```